# How to randomly select one nonzero element per row from a sparse matrix with out for loop in python

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, zero, rowwise

I have a large sparse matrix whose each row contains multiple nonzero elements, for example

```
a = np.array([[1, 1,0,0,0,0], [2,0, 1,0,2,0], [3,0,4,0,0, 3]])
```

I want to be able to randomly select one nonzero element per row without for loop. Any good suggestion? As output, I am more interested in chosen elements' index than its value.

Comment: Please add what you have tried.

Comment: I have used numpy.nonzero command but not able to get rid of for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a `numpy` `array` such as:

```
arr = np.array([5, 2, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6])
```

you can do `arr != 0` which will give a `True` / `False` `array` of values which pass the condition so in our case, where the values are *not equal* (`!=`) to `0`. So:

```
array([ True,  True,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

from here, we can `'index'` `arr` with this `boolean` `array` by doing `arr[arr != 0`] which gives us:

```
array([5, 2, 6, 2, 6])
```

So now that we have a way of removing the `non-zero` values from a `numpy` `array`, we can do a simple `list comprehension` on each `row` in your `a` `array`. For each `row`, we remove the `zeros` and then perform a `random.choice` on the `array`. As so:

```
np.array([np.random.choice(r[r!=0]) for r in a])
```

which gives you back an array of `length` `3` containing `random` `non-zero` items from each `row` in `a`.  **:)**

Hope this helps!

**Update**

If you want the `indexes` of the `random` `non-zero` numbers in the `array`, you can use `.nonzero()`.

So if we have this `array`:

```
arr = np.array([5, 2, 6, 0, 2, 0, 0, 6])
```

we can do:

```
arr.nonzero()
```

which gives a `tuple` of the `indexes` of `non-zero` `elements`:

```
(array([0, 1, 2, 4, 7]),)
```

so as with before, we can use this and `np.random.choice()` in a `list-comprehension` to produce random `indexes`:

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0], [3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3]])

np.array([np.random.choice(r.nonzero()[0]) for r in a])
```

which returns an `array` of the form `[x, y, z]` where `x`, `y` and `z` are `random` `indexes` of `non-zero` elements from their corresponding `rows`.

E.g. one result could be:

```
array([1, 4, 2])
```

And if you want it to also return the `rows`, you could just add in a `numpy.arrange()` call on the length of `a` to get an `array` of `row` numbers:

```
([np.arange(len(a))], np.array([np.random.choice(r.nonzero()[0]) for r in a]))
```

so an example `random` output could be:

```
([array([0, 1, 2])], array([1, 2, 5]))
```

for `a` as:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3]])
```

Hope this does what you want now **:)**

Comment: Thank you, Joe, it is very helpful. I am more interested in the index of the none zero elements, so the output of interest would be the indices of non-zero elements (one non-zero element per row)

Comment: @aminamollaysa as you have a `2 dimensional` `array` here, how would you like the `indicies`? As `tuples`? The values themselves? Oh and I know yo'ur new to the site, but if this answer was helpful, you can show by up voting (the little arrow) **:)**

Comment: yes, if we chose randomly one element per row, I want the output is the indices of that chosen element, for example:  the output can be [c, d] where c = [0, 1, 2 ] ( row index, which in fact is obvious)  d = [0, 4, 2] ( column index), simply, I just need the column index,  since we chose one element for each row.

Comment: @aminamollaysa I have updated the answer now using `.nonzero()`. It should do what you want now

Comment: Joe, Thank you very much, it is super clear and very helpful. Thank you for your time.